# Jquery- Form doesn't get my input value in first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

I have a form which has 2 inputs, really simple.

```
<form class="cform">
    <input type="text" name="cname" class="cname" id="cname" autofocus placeholder="Firstname Lastname">
    <div class="floatl regards"><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" id="submit"></div>
</form>
```

My JQuery is:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#submit").click(function()
    {
        var CName = $("#cname").val(); 
        console.log(CName);
    });
</script>
```

My problem is when I add a word in textbox and click on submit button it doesn't show anything in console unless I type the same word again and submit it! And it works on second click.
I notice that it doesn't work untile it add that words in the URL and I should write exactly the same word for the second time and click on submit if I want it to work!
How can I fix this error? which part of my code is wrong!?

Comment: Can you try wrapping the whole code inside `$(function () { /* code here*/ });`? It might work.

Comment: add -> return false; below  console.log(CName)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click on your button will submit the form using GET method to the current page that why you saw the word on the link after the click, all you need to prevent that is to change the type of button to `button` instead of `submit`, that will prevent the page from refresh :

```
<input type="text" name="cname" class="cname" id="cname" autofocus placeholder="Firstname Lastname">
```

Or you could add `e.preventDefault()` or `return false;` instead in your js code :

```
$("#submit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //That will prevent the click from submitting the form
     var CName = $("#cname").val(); 

     console.log(CName);

     return false; //Also prevent the click from submitting the form
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$("#submit").click(function(){
    var CName = $("#cname").val();
    console.log(CName);

    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="cform">
  <input type="text" name="cname" class="cname" id="cname" autofocus placeholder="Firstname Lastname">
  <div class="floatl regards"><input type="button" value="Submit" class="submit" id="submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I try changing input type to button. It works just when I click on that button but not when I press enter after writing my words in the text box. I add return false in the end of my jquery and it works. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the submit button the page will reload and your jQuery definition won't be recognized. In order to prevent that use a html button instead of a input submit button.

Or you can use `e.preventDefault();` inside your function call that will prevent to submit the form. In order to use that you have to pass the event as parameter using function(e) {}